# Unable to scale Sonarqube deployment

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, amazon-eks

I am running `Sonarqube 6.7` on `AWS EKS` as Deployment with 1 replica backed with RDS Database and EFS for persistent volume.
The moment I edit the deployment file to make the replicas count to 2, the new pod is entering into `CrashLoopBackOff`.
Let me know what all information you need, I would be happy to provide.

`CrashLoopBackOff` Pod Logs:

```
2019.01.21 06:20:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.01.21 06:20:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.01.21 06:20:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es
2019.01.21 06:20:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.01.21 06:20:17 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.01.21 06:20:17 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.01.21 06:20:22 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.01.21 06:20:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2019.01.21 06:20:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Comment: Can you try setting the sonar.log.level to DEBUG in the sonar.properties file?

Comment: Pod is not in Running status so I won't be able to exec into the pod in order to set the sonar.log.level to DEBUG. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Got DEBUG logs after adding DEBUG as an environment variable in the deployment file.

Comment: Not useful. It seems it's not possible to launch Sonarqube as a cluster. From sonar.properties file: When SonarQube runs standalone, a warning such as the following may appear in logs/es.log:
#      "max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]"
# When SonarQube runs as a cluster, however, Elasticsearch will refuse to start.
Could you please confirm?

Comment: Have a look at this [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-cluster/). is this what you want to realize?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solved by adding following in the deployment yaml in spec.template.spec

`securityContext:
   fsGroup: 999`